# CSS Progress bar styling issues

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, progress

I'm trying to create a header with a progress bar at the top. I'm trying to make it responsive. I've tried reading up about it and tried a few solutions but no success.  So my questions are:

1. How do I get the progress bar to shrink with the screen? So far I've used tables to organize the elements in and I can wrap the table but the progress bar itself won't shrink.
2. How do I right-align the progress bar so it shows on the right when full screen?

Here's my code:

```css
.header-style {
  background-color: #2A417B;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

.header-text {
  color: white;
  margin: 0em;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.header-style-logo {
  background-color: #2A417B;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em;
}

.table-wrap {
  display: block;
}

.table-wrap td {
  display: inline-block;
}

progress {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 1em;
  /* IE settings */
  color: #8FC23F;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
}


/* Chrome settings */

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: white;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #8FC23F;
}


/* Firefox settings */

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-style">
  <table class="table-wrap">
    <tr>
      <td><img class="header-style-logo" src="logo_white.png" width="111" height="72" /></td>
      <td>
        <h1 class="header-text"> My heading</h1>
      </td>
      <td> <progress value="5" max="100"></progress></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</header>
```

Comment: I wouldnt venture down the tables path as a method for responsive. Why are you using tables in the first place. Tables are used for Tabular data.

Comment: I need the logo, heading and progress bar to align. I tried using a few CSS methods to do this but no luck.

Comment: Best method for responsiveness is to break your page up into `divs`, you can go pretty far with them, it only takes a bit of extra styling for placement, etc. Like @Cam said, `tables` are not good for responsiveness.

Comment: @Samuel thats the perfect method to deploy to get the result you want. Try Bootstrap if you feel you need a framework to get the result.

Comment: @Cam I didn't ask the question man, it was Nix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve something like this via flexbox.

If you need elements on single line:

```css
.header-style {
  background-color: #2A417B;
  /* define as flex-container */
  /* by default items will be on single line */
  display: flex;
  /* center items */
  align-items: center;
}

.header-text {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.header-style-logo {
  background-color: #2A417B;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  /* don't shrink image */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}

progress {
  width: 50em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 1em;
  /* moving progress bar to right */
  margin-left: auto;
  /* IE settings */
  color: #8FC23F;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
}

/* Chrome settings */
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: white;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #8FC23F;
}

/* Firefox settings */
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-style">
  <img class="header-style-logo" src="logo_white.png" width="111" height="72" />
  <h1 class="header-text"> My heading</h1>
  <progress value="5" max="100"></progress>
</header>
```

If you want elements on multiple lines you need to add pseudoelement with `margin-left: auto` to push it to right and CSS `order` value less than `progress`. Demo:

```css
.header-style {
  background-color: #2A417B;
  /* define as flex-container */
  display: flex;
  /* center items */
  align-items: center;
  /* allow moving items to new line */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header-text {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.header-style-logo {
  background-color: #2A417B;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em;
  /* don't shrink image */
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.header-style:after {
  content: "";
  /* adding order to display before progress bar */
  order: 0;
  /* move to the right */
  margin-left: auto;
}

progress {
  width: 50em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 1em;
  /* IE settings */
  color: #8FC23F;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  /* display after pseudoelment */
  order: 1;
}

/* Chrome settings */
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: white;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #8FC23F;
}

/* Firefox settings */
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-style">
  <img class="header-style-logo" src="logo_white.png" width="111" height="72" />
  <h1 class="header-text"> My heading</h1>
  <div class="margin-left-auto">
  </div>
  <progress value="5" max="100"></progress>
</header>
```

Comment: I suggest using flex-wrap: no-wrap; if you want the progress bar to always be on the same line and use  flex-shrink: 0; on your image, so it does not shrink when resizing! :D

Comment: @Nix Improved my answer to both multiline (no need for media queries now) and single line versions.

Answer (score 2):

Could try something like this with percentages:

```css
.header-style {
  background-color: #2A417B;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

.header-text {
  color: white;
  margin: 0em;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.header-style-logo {
  background-color: #2A417B;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em;
}

progress {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  /* IE settings */
  color: #8FC23F;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
}
td.logo{
  width: 10%;
}
td.heading{
  width: 10%;
}
td.progress{
  width: 80%;
}

/* Chrome settings */

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: white;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #8FC23F;
}


/* Firefox settings */

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-style">
  <table class="table-wrap">
    <tr>
      <td class="logo"><img class="header-style-logo" src="logo_white.png" width="111" height="72" /></td>
      <td class="heading">
        <h1 class="header-text"> My heading</h1>
      </td>
      <td class="progress"> <progress value="5" max="100"></progress></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</header>
```

Comment: This works great for the tables, thank you. I've decided to take some advice from those more experienced than me and ditch the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using css flex method to manage your content. The Document Object Model, is what defines the logical structure of your page and it is good practice to keep the logical structure, logical. Using table for anything other then storing tabular data, is not a good practice.

The reason your progress bar is not responding to changes of view-port/screensize is that the browser is struggling to read a measure of em (Attributed to font size). Using % as the unit of measure for your progress bar will dynamically control its size.

```css
.header-style {
  background-color: #2A417B;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

.header-text {
  color: white;
  margin: 0em;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.header-style-logo {
  background-color: #2A417B;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em;
}

.table-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

progress {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 1em;
  /* IE settings */
  color: #8FC23F;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
}

/* Chrome settings */

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: white;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #8FC23F;
}

/* Firefox settings */

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: white;
}
img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-style">
  <div class="table-wrap">
       <img class="header-style-logo" src="logo_white.png" width="111" height="72" />
       <h1 class="header-text">My heading</h1>
       <progress value="5" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for bring flex properties to my attention. Should have thought about that. Much appreciated.